# Problem with parse string to datetime - String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#

I have some problem with parse string to datime. I am comparing whether the date is less than the date now and then give another bacground for cells in Gridview.

```
 protected void TabulkaZakazkyAktivni_DataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
 {
    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (DateTime.ParseExact((gvr.Cells[11].Text), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            gvr.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(gvr.Cells[11].Text);
        }
    }

}
```

String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

EDIT 1:
Inside gvr.Cells[11] is "2019-05-19 10:19:48.000    "

Comment: Was the string `null` or `empty`? You can use `DateTime.TryParse` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) to check for a valid datetime instead of `DateTime.ParseExact`

Comment: And what's inside `gvr.Cells[11]`?

Comment: Inside is "2019-05-19 10:19:48.000 "

Comment: That is format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff`, not sure why you are using `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: When i use format yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff then is the same error

Comment: Works for me: [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HTG7Dg). You need to create an [mvce] if you want more help, see my dotfiddle link as example. For now I am voting to close as "why is my code not working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way:

```
protected void TabulkaZakazkyAktivni_DataBound1(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (gvr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (DateTime.Parse(gvr.Cells[11].Text) < DateTime.Now)
        {
            gvr.Cells[11].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            Label2.Text = Convert.ToString(gvr.Cells[11].Text);
        }
    }
}
```